# Adding a CSS class to span tag when corresponding image is slide in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a two phase animation including a div full of images and to the right, a paragraph of 10 span sentences. The images are absolute, so they stack on top of each other and have a negative margin initially to hide the image, by overflow: hidden.

On phase 1 (when page loads and before user hovers over a span), the images are set at a 5 second interval per image to loop through the images in an infinite manner. This phase and it's interval will clear when the second phase happens, which is when you hover over a span tag, in which the corresponding image slides in to view.

I have phase 1 and phase 2 coded, but my question is: In phase 1, I have to implement it so that when it's animating through the images by default, the corresponding span tag has to have a CSS class just like when you hover over the span tag in phase 2.

Here is the code if anyone wants to fiddle around with it:

```
<!--begin:content-->
                <div id="content">

                        <div id="pics">
                            <img src="ADD ANY IMAGE" id="defaultImg" alt="" />
                            <img src="ADD ANY IMAGE" id="hover_1_pic" alt="" />
                            <img src="ADD ANY IMAGE" id="hover_2_pic" alt="" />
                            <img src="ADD ANY IMAGE" id="hover_3_pic" alt="" />
                            <img src="ADD ANY IMAGE" id="hover_4_pic" alt="" />
                            <img src="ADD ANY IMAGE" id="hover_5_pic" alt="" />
                            <img src="ADD ANY IMAGE" id="hover_6_pic" alt="" />
                            <img src="ADD ANY IMAGE" id="hover_7_pic" alt=""  />
                            <img src="ADD ANY IMAGE" id="hover_8_pic" alt="" />
                            <img src="ADD ANY IMAGE" id="hover_9_pic" alt="" />
                            <img src="ADD ANY IMAGE" id="hover_10_pic" alt="" />
                        </div>

                        <!--begin: homeText - block of span tags w/text referenced in jQuery -->
                        <div class="homeText">    
                            <p>
                                <span id="hover_1" >evolve water.</span>
                                <span id="hover_2">stream the party.</span>
                                <br />
                                <span id="hover_3">let moms play.</span>
                                <span id="hover_4">play on big screens.</span>
                                <br /> 
                                <span id="hover_5">turn txt into sport.</span>
                                <span id="hover_6">have 18 wheels.</span>
                                <br />
                                <span id="hover_7">have chapters.</span>
                                <span id="hover_8">personify an issue.</span>
                                <br />
                                <span id="hover_9">transform neighborhoods.</span>
                                <br />
                                <span id="hover_10">become keepsakes</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>

            </div><!--end content-->
```

CSS

```
#pics img {
height: 131px;
width: 334px;
position: absolute;
margin-left:-325px;
}

/*  ADDED by ben sewards   */
#pics {
height:179px;
width:335px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin:0px;
padding-top:15px;
margin-left:49px;
float:left;
}

/*  ADDED by ben sewards   */
.homeText {
width:600px;
height:240px;
padding-left:15px;
padding-top: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
float:left;
}

.homeText p {
line-height: 115%;
font-family: @Adobe Fangsong Std R;
font-size: 2.6em;
font-weight:bolder;
color: #c0c0c0;
margin: 0px;
}

.homeText span:hover {
background-color:Lime;
color: White;
cursor: pointer;
}

.span-background-change {
background-color:Lime;
color: White;
}
```

JS Script

```
$('document').ready(function () {
slideIn('defaultImg');
timer = setInterval('slideInNext()', 5000);
functionHover();
});

var slideSpeed = 500;

var slideIn = function (id) {
$('#' + id).addClass('active').animate({ 'margin-left': '0px' }, { 'duration':             slideSpeed, 'easing': 'swing', 'queue': true });
}
var slideOutCurrent = function () {
$('#pics img.active').removeClass('active').animate({ 'margin-left': '325px' }, {     'duration': slideSpeed, 'easing': 'swing', 'queue': true, 'complete': function () {         $(this).css('margin-left', '-325px'); } });
}

var slideInNext = function () {
var curImage = $('#pics img.active');
var nextImage = curImage.next();
if (nextImage.length == 0) {
    nextImage = $('#pics img:first');
}
slideOutCurrent();
slideIn(nextImage.attr('id'));
}

var queueToSlideIn = [];
var mouseOnTimer = null;
var mouseOffTimer = null;

var functionHover = function () {
$('.homeText span').hover(
//binding 2 handlers to hover event
function () {   //when hovering over a span - mousenenter
    clearTimeout(mouseOffTimer);
    clearInterval(timer);
    var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
    mouseOnTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        if (!$('#' + thisId + '_pic').hasClass('active')) {
            addToQueue(thisId + '_pic');
        }
    }, 300);
},
function () {   //when off of span - mouseleave
    clearTimeout(mouseOnTimer);
    mouseOffTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        if (!$('#defaultImg').hasClass('active')) {
            addToQueue('defaultImg');
        }
    }, 500);
}
);
$('.homeText span').click(function () {
    //set current span on click
    $span = $(this).attr('id');
    //navigate to corresponding case study
    var href = $('#' + $span + '_pic').attr('alt');
    window.location.href = href;
});
}

var addToQueue = function (id) {
queueToSlideIn.push(id);
$('#pics').queue(function () { animateNext(); $(this).dequeue(); }).delay(slideSpeed);
}

var animateNext = function () {
if (queueToSlideIn.length > 0) {
    var id = queueToSlideIn.shift();
    slideOutCurrent();
    slideIn(id);
}
};
```

Sorry if the indenting is messy.

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this snippet of code to my slideInNext function for desired results:

```
if (nextImage.attr('id') != "defaultImg") {
    //add class to corresponding span tag of current image
    var spanId = nextImage.attr('id');
    //corresponing span of next image
    spanId = spanId.substring(0, spanId.length - 4);
    $('#' + spanId).addClass('span-background-change');
}
```

I just used the substring method in javascript to pull apart the images attribute id and place it in a local variable to represent the span id.

Answer (score 1):

I added anew class which is a duplicate of your hover class:

```
    .homeText-hover {
background-color:Lime;
color: White;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Then I added two line each to your SlideIn and slideOutCurrent functions:

```
var slideIn = function (id) {
var slId = id.split('_pic');
$('#' + slId[0]).addClass('homeText-hover');
$('#' + id).addClass('active').animate({ 'margin-left': '0px' }, { 'duration':             slideSpeed, 'easing': 'swing', 'queue': true });
}
var slideOutCurrent = function () {
var slId = $('#pics img.active').attr('id').split('_pic');
$('#' + slId[0]).removeClass('homeText-hover');
$('#pics img.active').removeClass('active').animate({ 'margin-left': '325px' }, {     'duration': slideSpeed, 'easing': 'swing', 'queue': true, 'complete': function () {         $(this).css('margin-left', '-325px'); } });
}
```

Your autoslide isn't working out in FF...

Comment: I like your idea, but it can get complicated where slideIn is being used in other helper methods. I kept it simplistic and added the appropriate code to the slideInNext function, although my code is similar to yours. Thanks again!

Comment: I will post my answer in 5 hours.

Comment: Basically you need to find a relationship that consistantly links your objects.

Answer (score 1):

I like your solution, Ben. Another solution that uses the same principle of selecting identifying attributes would be to add a class, unique to each img-span pair, to each of the elements,  so that each shares a specific class with its corresponding element.

Below is an explanation of the use of classes as flags,  which I originally posted in a solution to a different question that has since been closed:

***Classes as Flags***

Adding a class to an element does not always mean that you are going to be giving it some new CSS styles. CSS is a language that USES CLASSES in order TO HELP identify elements to style a particular way; classes are NOT FOR THE SOLE PURPOSE of applying CSS to an element. Were this not the case, CSS would only be able to style elements through the use of classes, and not through the use of other selectors (IDs, parents, children, descendants, etc.).

Developers often use classes as "flags." Flags are a way of signaling something about a particular element without having to store that information in a variable. For example, imagine you have a list of elements and all the elements are styled exactly the same, via a CSS class. If a developer wanted to mark every other element in this list in a particular way (for some later use), without changing the style of the elements, he may choose to add a second class called "alternate" to the elements.

You can add as many classes as you want to an element and it is totally accepted coding style to add multiple classes that do not have any associated styles (provided that such classes are for some other use -scripting, etc.).